# How to undo the effect of glTranslatef

Tags: c++, opengl

Let's say that I want to translate a polygon.If before drawing it I use glTranslatef it gets translated, but if I want to draw two polygons and translate only one, how do I do?

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include "utility.h"

void init()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
}

void render()
{
    glClearColor(APPLE_GRAY);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor4f(RED);
    glVertex2f(0,0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor4f(BLUE);
    glVertex2f(0.5,0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5,0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

I want to translate only the triangle, not the square.How to do that?

Comment: Totally off topic, but I has to be said: Modern versions of OpenGL no longer support either GL_POLYGON, nor immediate mode (glBegin…glEnd) nor the built-in matrix stack. In all its aspects your question tackles topics that are no longer relevant in modern OpenGL.

Comment: @datenwolf that's too bad, I'm studying this at university.

Comment: Well, please tell your TA and/or professors, that they're teaching way outdated stuff. Immediate mode has been deprecated (i.e. should no longer be used) ever since OpenGL-2 (in fact in the initial design of OpenGL-2 immediate mode and display lists were already on the agenda to be removed – it took until OpenGL-3 core for this to actually happen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you translate, call:

`glPushMatrix()`

Then after drawing the first polygon, call:

`glPopMatrix()`

I've also noted you have no `glEnd()` call after your first polygon.  Additionally, unless there is more code that's not listed, I notice that you don't switch from the modelview to the projection matrix when calling `glOrtho()`.  This isn't strictly necessary if you are only using the modelview matrix for this example, but the traditional approach is to set up your projection like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

Then, your render function sets up the modelview matrix for polygon rendering.  Again, not a requirement and your example looks like it will do what you need since you are only using one matrix.

Reference:  [glPushMatrix() OpenGL Documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml)